# How do I add the 2,4,6 .... labels on my X axies in Google-sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Can't find the option to set up this.

Any tips?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the chart and adjust Major step value to 1. See attached.

[image]